# regex work on regex101 but doesn't work on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I use a regex convert `<a>` with images url to `<img>`

```js
var message='<a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://example.com/example.jpg</a>';
message.replace(/<a.*>(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))<\/a>/gi,'<img src="$1">');
console.log(message);
//expect: <img src="http://example.com/example.jpg">
```

[image: work on regex101]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace` doesn't change the string it's called on, but return a new string. Just change to:

```js
var message='<a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://example.com/example.jpg</a>';
message = message.replace(/<a.*>(https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg))<\/a>/gi,'<img src="$1">');
console.log(message);
//expect: <img src="http://example.com/example.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` doesn't replace the original string, it return a new string that is the result of the replacemet, you have to store that new string in a variable and log it like this:

```js
var message='<a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">http://example.com/example.jpg</a>';


var result = message.replace(/<a.*>(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))<\/a>/gi,'<img src="$1">');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var message='<a href="http://example.com/example.jpg" target="_blank"     
  rel="noopener noreferrer">http://example.com/example.jpg</a>';
  var newString=message.replace(/<a.*>(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))<\/a>/gi,'<img src=$1">');
  alert(newString);
```

You need to consume the new string, replace wont rewrite.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword! Your code won't work!

Comment: thanks lad, @ibrahimmahrir , edited :)